# Can I use a name of a deleted pointer?

Tags: c++11, pointers, redeclare

Is it allowed to use a pointer's name of a pointer once deleted?

This code, for instance, won't compile.

```
    int hundred = 100;
    int * const finger = &hundred;
    delete finger;

    int * finger = new int; // error: conflicting declaration 'int* finger'
```

This won't either:

```
    int hundred = 100;
    int * const finger = &hundred;
    delete finger;

    int finger = 50; // error: conflicting declaration 'int finger'
```

Comment: The pointer itself is not deleted, only the thing it is pointing to. So the pointer still exists and you cannot use that name in the same scope for something different. Also please never delete something that you did not create with `new`, this is a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `int *` is still an living object. The lifetime of the `int` that it pointed to has ended.

Note that

```
int hundred = 100;
int * const finger = &hundred;
delete finger;
```

has undefined behaviour, as you have attempted to `delete` an object that was not allocated by `new`.

In general, `new` and `delete` should not appear in C++ programs. Owning pointers should be `std::unique_ptr` (or rarely `std::shared_ptr` or other user-defined smart pointer type).